# capistrano 3 deploy RoR App error: ln: failed to create symbolic link : File exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano3

I'm attempting to deploy my with Capistrano 3, but failed.

It returned such a error:

** Invoke deploy:symlink:shared (first_time)
** Execute deploy:symlink:shared
** Invoke deploy:symlink:linked_files (first_time)
** Execute deploy:symlink:linked_files
** Invoke deploy:symlink:linked_dirs (first_time)
** Execute deploy:symlink:linked_dirs
INFO[8051297e] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -pv /home/wango/apps/wango/releases/20140929084104/public on 101.227.244.212
INFO[b6759259] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -pv /home/wango/apps/wango/releases/20140929084104/public on wango.cc
INFO[8051297e] Finished in 0.024 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO[b6759259] Finished in 0.025 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO[871fe15d] Running /usr/bin/env ln -s /home/wango/apps/wango/shared/public/assets /home/wango/apps/wango/releases/20140929084104/public/assets on 101.227.244.212
INFO[bca7add7] Running /usr/bin/env ln -s /home/wango/apps/wango/shared/public/assets /home/wango/apps/wango/releases/20140929084104/public/assets on wango.cc
INFO[871fe15d] Finished in 0.023 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing on host wango.cc: ln exit status: 1
ln stdout: Nothing written
ln stderr: ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘/home/wango/apps/wango/releases/20140929084104/public/assets/assets’: File exists

In my releases folder, there are more than one 'assets' folders:

/releases/20140929084104/public/assets/assets

How can I fixed it?

And this is my deploy.rb:

```
# config valid only for Capistrano 3.1
lock '3.2.1'

set :application, 'wango'
set :repo_url, 'git@bitbucket.org:jofone/wango.git'
set :branch, 'master'

set :user, 'wango'
set :deploy_to, "/home/#{fetch(:user)}/apps/#{fetch(:application)}"
set :scm, :git

set :format, :pretty
set :log_level, :info
set :pty, true

# set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml config/app_config.yml}
# set :linked_dirs, %w{bin log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system}

# Default value for default_env is {}
# set :default_env, { path: "/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH" }

set :keep_releases, 5

namespace :deploy do

  desc "Check that we can access everything"
    task :check_write_permissions do
      on roles(:all) do |host|
        if test("[ -w #{fetch(:deploy_to)} ]")
          info "#{fetch(:deploy_to)} is writable on #{host}"
        else
          error "#{fetch(:deploy_to)} is not writable on #{host}"
        end
      end
    end

  desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      sudo "service #{fetch(:application)}_server restart"
      sudo "service nginx restart"
    end
  end

  after :publishing, :restart

  after :restart, :clear_cache do
    on roles(:web), in: :groups, limit: 3, wait: 10 do
      # Here we can do anything such as:
      # within release_path do
      #   execute :rake, 'cache:clear'
      # end
    end
  end

end

# namespace :assets do
#   before :backup_manifest, 'deploy:assets:create_manifest_json'
#   task :create_manifest_json do
#     on roles :web do
#       within release_path do
#         execute :mkdir, release_path.join('assets_manifest_backup')
#       end
#     end
#   end
# end

set :puma_rackup, -> { File.join(current_path, 'config.ru') }
set :puma_state, "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.state"
set :puma_pid, "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.pid"
set :puma_bind, "unix://#{shared_path}/tmp/sockets/puma.sock"
set :puma_conf, "#{shared_path}/puma.rb"
set :puma_access_log, "#{shared_path}/log/puma_error.log"
set :puma_error_log, "#{shared_path}/log/puma_access.log"
set :puma_role, :app
set :puma_env, fetch(:rack_env, fetch(:rails_env, 'production'))
set :puma_threads, [0, 16]
set :puma_workers, 0
set :puma_init_active_record, true
set :puma_preload_app, true
```

Comment: ,can u please share your deploy.rb file and let us know the configurations??

Comment: there are more than one manifest.json file in my '/shared/public/assets/' folder, and 'current/public/assets/' has a 'assets' sub-folder.